# What does this syntax '${$key} = $val' inside a loop mean in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, loops, foreach

It's time to stop searching a just ask. I can't find an answer online for the life of me. Anyway, I am going through someone else's code and they have this syntax inside of a loop and I'm not sure exactly what is happening.

```
foreach($params as $key => $val) {
    ${$key} = $val
}
```

It's the ${$key} that I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's assigning all the key-value pairs in an array to actual variables.

`${$key}` is evaluated twice. It takes the `$key` for that value and evaluates it to a string. So if `$key` were the string 'foo' then the final operation being done would be `$foo = $val`.

Answer (score 4):

This is called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.variable.php). In your loop, the code will set the variable who's name is `$key` to the value `$val`.

The loop could be replaced with [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract).

Answer (score 3):

This essentially does what `extract()` does:

```
$params = array('a' => 'foo', 'b' => 'bar');

foreach($params as $key => $val) {
    ${$key} = $val
}

echo $a; // outputs 'foo'
echo $b; // outputs 'bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called Variable variables http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php.
If the `$key = 'test'`, then `${$key} === $test.`
And so the result will be `$test = $val`.